# rewriting images directory with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so here is the old address

```
http://sie.com/files/images/2013/12/600x415_img.jpg
```

note that all the image names are starting with `600x`

also 
2 directories before image `2013/12/` are dynamically created and can be different for other images depending on month/year

i want to redirect all these links to (all 600x images have been moved to new directory )

```
http://sie.com/thumbs/images/2013/12/600x415_img.jpg
```

basically replacing `files` with `thumbs`

this is what i have but it doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^files/images/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/600x(.*)$ thumbs/images/$1/$2/600x$3[L]
```

---

here is my current htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img\.site\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(images/.+)$ site.com/files/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
RewriteRule ^files/images/(\d+)/(\d+)/600x(.*)$ /thumbs/images/$1/$2/600x$3 [L]
```